# What is that sound?

Tags: vw, noise, golf

I have a 2004 VW Golf Variant. There's no problem, I'm just curious.

Just after I have opened the driver's side door, a small motor runs for about one second, then stops. This also happens if I stay seated after stopping the car, and then open the door after some time has passed.

I am certain that it is not related to the door opening/locking mechanism. Perhaps it could be the fuel pump pre-charging the engine (if it even does that...)? While and after starting the engine, I can't hear that sound (but that may be because it's being drowned out).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the sound of the fuel pump priming and pressurizing the fuel lines, which is absolutely normal. VW likes to use the opening of the driver door to trigger fuel rail pressurization.

In fact, one could use the absence of the sound of the fuel pump as a tell-tale sign that the fuel pump relay is not functioning properly. As @Paulster2 points out, either that or the fuel pump itself needs investigating.

Comment: I would say you could use it as a sign the fuel pump relay or *just the fuel pump* itself, but exactly.

Comment: @Paulster2 : True